# git-p4 rebase command fails when using "main" as the default git branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using the git-p4 script ([doc reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4), [code reference](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-p4.py)) to drive some processes to synchronize code stored in Perforce Helix in to GitLab. It works fine for my needs, though now that GitLab defaults to default branch names of "main", I'm having some grief. I want to use the "main" default branch names, not "master".

The current sticking point is when I run a `git p4 rebase`, I get this reply:

```
Error: no branch refs/remotes/p4/master; perhaps specify one with --branch.
Performing incremental import into refs/remotes/p4/master git branch
Depot paths: //path/to/my/p4/depot
Failure with: git p4 rebase
```

I would be happy to use a --branch flag with git-p4, but it doesn't actually support this.

Any pro-tips out there?